# Directus - Cancel action hook before creation

Tags: hook, directus

Is there any way to cancel an action hook on Directus before the data writing on database?

Ex. I want to send an complex email using a hook and not writing the data on database.

Yes, i know that Directus has a endpoint for email, but it's very simple and no meet my necessities.

To be clear: What is the method for canceling an action or filter? Anybody know?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Using an event hook... by default, the Hooks occur after an event has happened. But you can append `:before` to the end to explicitly specify when the Hook should fire. This would allow you to send an email and/or cancel the action.

```
item.delete:before
```

https://docs.directus.io/extensions/hooks.html#creating-hooks

Comment: Thanks for your response! How I cancel the action?

I don't know what I have to write in the code to cancel a action. The question is about that.

Comment: Here are the docs for Directus 9: https://github.com/directus/next/blob/main/docs/guides/extensions/api-hooks.md#before

Comment: How can I cancel then the event in directus 10 without just throwing an error? The link for Directus 9 is not working any more.